# Variation between MonteCarlo mean score and static LCA score

Tags: brightway

When I try to apply MonteCarlo calculations, I notice that the mean of the MC results is systematically higher than the static results

For instance, with the production of Li-ion cell in China :

```
cell=[i for i in bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.8_APOS') if i['name'] == 'battery cell production, Li-ion, NMC111' and i['location']=='CN'][0]
```

The static LCA score for GWP is equal to 18.3 kgCO2eq/kg cell :

```
CC = [method for method in bw.methods if "('EF v3.0 no LT', 'climate change no LT', 'global warming potential (GWP100) no LT')" in str(method)][0]

lca=LCA({cell:1},CC)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.score
```

And when we compute the MC for 100 iterations :

```
MC = bw.MonteCarloLCA({cell:1}, CC)
scores = [next(MC) for i in range(100)]
```

The mean MC score is really higher than the static one : by doing `np.mean(scores)` we get something near 20 kgCO2eq/kg.
If I repeat several times the MC computations, the MC mean value seems to be always higher than the static value (even with a large number of iterations), and I cannot understand why.

I tried to look at the uncertainty of the activity but it seems normally defined for each exchanges (lognormal uncertainty mostly here).
I also tried this for others random activies of the EcoInvent Database and I always have the same conclusion

Does it come from the uncertainty representation in the EcoInvent DataBase or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most uncertainty in ecoinvent is defined with the lognormal distribution, and the static value given in inventory datasets is the *median*, not the average, of this distribution. The mean of the lognormal is always higher than the median, so it is normal to get higher average values from Monte Carlo uncertainty analysis.

You can read more about [the lognormal in LCA](https://chris.mutel.org/ecoinvent-lognormal.html) and [the representative value of the lognormal](https://chris.mutel.org/too-confusing.html).

Comment: Thank you. The explanations in your blog were really clear for me. I enjoy being not the only one to be surprised by these results !

Comment: I understand why the mean value of the MC results is higher than the static value but i have still a question after reading your notes. Actually, it doesn't explain why the median of the MC values is not equal to the static values ? Let's look at an activity Z that needs X kg of an activity that emits Y kg of CO2. The total emissions (static values) should be 'exp(µ_x) *exp(µ_y)' and the median of  MC iterations on the lognormal distribution Z should be also 'exp(µ_x) *exp(µ_y)'. I guess I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

As of `brightway2-io 0.9.dev22`, the parameter `reparametrize_lognormals=True` can be passed to the constructor of `SingleOutputEcospold2Importer`. This ensures that the lognormal distribution for exchanges is parametrized such that the mean value of the lognormal distribution is equal to the (static) amount for that exchange.

An upgrade to a recent version and a re-import of ecoinvent should therefore fix your issue.